WPF SnapToDevicePixels does not really function
As far as I understand, SnapToDevicePixels should make sure, that a Control should be aligned to pixels.
Now I observe the following. I'm using a GridSplitter to divide the window. In the lower panel I position a user control. Whenever the ActualHeight of the container below the GridSplitter has decimal place, there seems to be some kind of a sub pixel offset even if SnapToDevicePixels is set on the user control.

Mouse.GetPosition(userControl) reports decimal places for the y-axis. Windows scaling is 100%. The decimal places of the y-axis and the decimal places of the actual size of the container below the GridSplitter are the same.
Rendering a white rectangle (Rect(-10,-10, 20, 20)) at the top left corner with ClipToBounds=true result in gray lines at the top, whenever the container below the GridSplitter that holds the user control has decimal places. I would expect, that SnapToDevicePixels would force ClipToBounds to cut off drawing at pixel boundries.

Is there a know problem with SnapToDevicePixels and GridSplitter?
